# Why is "in" operation in Python faster than iterating a list?

Tags: python, iteration, documentation

For example, I want to determine if a certain number a is in a list A. If I use `return a in A`, this would be much faster than writing an iteration function like

```
for number in A: 
    if a == number:
        return True
```

What's under the hood? Is Python using a different way as mine to determine the membership? I skimmed the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) but didn't find the answer.

Comment: It gets pushed into C code, assuming you are talking about CPython

Comment: @roganjosh I'm pretty sure that even without CPython, if `A` is a built in `list` object then the implementation of `in` is still in C.

Answer (score 0):

**6.10.2. Membership test operations**

For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`.

For the string and bytes types, `x in y` is `True` if and only if x is a substring of y. An equivalent test is `y.find(x) != -1`. Empty strings are always considered to be a substring of any other string, so `"" in "abc"` will return `True`.

For user-defined classes which define the `__contains__()` method, `x in y` returns `True` if `y.__contains__(x)` returns a true value, and `False` otherwise.

For user-defined classes which do not define `__contains__()` but do define `__iter__()`, `x in y` is `True` if some value `z` with `x == z` is produced while iterating over `y`. If an exception is raised during the iteration, it is as if `in` raised that exception.

Lastly, the old-style iteration protocol is tried: if a class defines `__getitem__()`, `x in y` is `True` if and only if there is a non-negative integer index `i` such that `x == y[i]`, and all lower integer indices do not raise IndexError exception. (If any other exception is raised, it is as if in raised that exception).

Information extracted from the Python official page: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html